# Why does strncpy() return a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, strncpy

Why does `strncpy()` return a pointer, when `char *dest` gets assigned anyway?

Is this simply a design decision to make it more flexible?

Comment: Standard warning: `strncpy` is a poorly named function, that can lead to subtle buffer overflow bugs if incorrectly used (which is easy to do accidentally). It should be avoided.

Comment: @usr Read the question before marking as duplicate !!